# How to read an MSMQ message object from a queue as a string of the message body

Tags: msmq

Is it possible to read a message from a queue directly as a string (the same Message Body you see when looking at an MSMQ message from the Computer Management MSC snap-in) so that I can persist it to a database myself?  I want to be able to store it for replay later without losing any data and I am worried if deserialize/serialize it I could lose something.

Comment: Are you only interested in saving the message body and no other message properties?

Comment: Just to be sure: You want to intercept every Message in the queue and get a copy of the Message Body but leave the Message otherwise unaltered?

Answer (score 5):

try this..

```
string QueueName = @".\private$\publishingQueue"; 

//note, you cannot use method exists on remote queues

if (MessageQueue.Exists(QueueName))
{

 var queue = new MessageQueue(queueInfo.QueueName)
 {
 MessageReadPropertyFilter = new MessagePropertyFilter
 {
      ArrivedTime = true,
      Body = true
     }
 };


 var messages = queue.GetAllMessages();
 var m = messages[0];
 m.Formatter = new System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter(new String[] {});

 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(m.BodyStream);

 string ms = "";
 string line;

 while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
 {
      ms += sr.ReadLine();
 }

 //ms now contains the message      
 }
```